# Return all items with string

Tags: jquery, string

The function below returns all items in a list if string value matches all. How do i change it to return any?

```
function StringContainsAllItems(stringVal, items) {
if (items.length == 0 || items.length == null) {
    return false;
}

for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    console.log("Item: " + items[i]);
    if (stringVal.indexOf(items[i]) == -1) {
        return false;
    }
}

return true;
}
```

Here's my [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/amesy/u81ubp5x/)

Basically i'm trying to return any items that have any of the values, currently only returns if it has all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the condition in the loop to return `true` if `stringVal.indexOf(items[i]) > -1` and so if it gets through the loop and didn't find anything, then `return false`.

```
function StringContainsAnyItems(stringVal, items) {    
    for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
        console.log("Item: " + items[i]);
        if (stringVal.indexOf(items[i]) > -1) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: 2 seconds too late, it would be nice if you would rename your function to StringContainsAnyItems.

Comment: You also changed the default return to false (instead of true).

Comment: Thanks for this, it doesn't quite do what i want it to. I should have been clearer, so i've provided a fiddle above and edited my post explaining more.

Comment: @Amesey So you want an array containing only the items that match `stringVal`?

Comment: Please ignore my last comment, i just copied and pasted the code above and it works. I must have mis typed something :)